# Nested for loops with linked indexes

Tags: r, for-loop, indexing

I just got a simple question for you. It concerns nested for loops code in R.
I got this kind of algorithm to develop:
[image: Equation 1]

[image: Equation 2]

N = 180; k = 1 ... N; l = 1...k; alpha = 1

So I tried this nested for loop, but it was a disaster.

```
 N <- 180
nu <- 0
for (k in 1:N) {
     for (l in 1:k) {
        nu<- nu + 1/(N-l+1)
   }
 E<- N*nu
print(E)
}
```

I got 180 E values, but all of them are wrong.
For example, for k = 10 I expect to get a nu = 0.057 and a related E[10] = 10.26. Whereas script returns me a E[10] = 55.94.

I really cannot figure out why.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You keep summing on nu, here is a fix for the problem. When calculating a new E at the first for loop just zero the nu again.

This return the expected result:

```
N <- 180
nu <- 0

for (k in 1:N) {
  nu <- 0
  for (l in 1:k) {
    nu <- nu + 1/(N-l+1)
  }
  E<- N*nu
  print(E)
}
```

And, below is a somewhat better solution using the sum function instead of looping.

```
### Functions
vk <- function(k, alpha, N) {
   return(sum(1 / (N - 1:k + 1)^alpha))
}

E <- function(N, k) {
  return(N * vk(k, 1, N))
}

N <- 180 
k <- N 

result.vec <- rep(NA, k) 
for (i in 1:k) {
  result.vec[i] <- E(N, i)
}
```